# Can I Compare Symbol to String

Tags: computer-science, pattern-matching

I'm a student majoring in computer science.

I'm not sure if I can use the equality sign (=) for a string value.
(I can definitely do that in computer code...)

So please check the mathematical representation bellow.

[image]

I want to firmly define pattern matching between $P'$ and $P$.

For P' to be matched by $P$, for all elements of $P'$,

$P'_i$ (it is string value) should be equal to $P_i$ or 
$P_i$ is equal to underscore (_).

Is there any problem to use the representation above?

Thank you!

---

[image]

I edited the representation based on some feedback!

Are there still things to improve?

Comment: Yes, that is fine. The symbol for equality, $=$, is for comparing any type of object, including strings. As a small LaTeX note, I would use `\bigwedge` instead of `\wedge` (or `\land`); and your $false$ is badly kerned, you might want to use `\mathrm{false}` or `\text{false}`.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Thanks for very good tips! How about underscore? Would it be better to use "_" instead?

Comment: I think it depends on how the rest of your notation looks. The most important thing of mathematical notation is to be easily understood and precise; using the word 'underscore' seems perfectly clear here, but if you've previously established that the alphabet over which $P$ is defined includes the underscore symbol, and it makes sense from context that that would function as a sort of wildcard, then "\_" (or maybe '_', since an element of a string is often a character instead of a string) is perhaps aesthetically better.

Answer (score 0):

I would write:

$$
\operatorname{matched}(P,P')=
\begin{cases}
\text{false} & |P|\ne|P'|\\
\bigwedge_\limits{i=1}^{|P|} \left(P_i=P'_i \lor \_\right) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Now we know what parameter 'matched' takes. Also it is customary to use $P$ instead of $P'$ where possible. The stop value for the global AND should be on the top. And the logic for case $2$ can be contracted.

Comment: It really seems like a programming function. Can I write P'.isMatchedBy(P) = ...?